# How to center an image inside a button, using jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm new to jQuery mobile and Phonegap. Sorry if this is not the place to ask for this question.

I'm trying to put a custom image inside a button (not the small icon to the left or to the right but a bigger image).

**I use the following code:**

```
<a data-role="button" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" >
    <img src="images/car.png" />
</a>
```

In the rendering, the image is not centered but goes right.

I have also tried using a `class="car-icon"` and the corresponding css3 rule:

```
.ui-icon-car-icon {
    background-image: url("car.png");   
}

.ui-icon-car-icon {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated (I have spent the whole night trying to fix this).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the  thing, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/den232/sFupf/

```
      <button><img src="http://doc.jsfiddle.net/_downloads/jsfiddle-logo.png" height=35 width=35 ></button>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting your image as the `background` of your link `<a>`, and centering it using `background-position: center center;`:

**HTML:**

```
<a id="mybutton" data-role="button" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" >&nbsp;</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
#mybutton {
    background: url('car.png') no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    background-position: center center; 
}
```